# countinuous,differentiable and integrable functions.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I am looking for a continuous function G:R^2--> R which is differentiable everywhere except at (0,0). And another H:R^2-->R which is not integrable. I don't how or where from do I start.
Any hints or tips?? 
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide more background ? Where are those questions coming from?

Comment: I decided to learn more maths in quarantine time, I found these questions on a homework sheet somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint.* For the first, do you know a function *of one variable* that is differentiable everywhere apart from the origin? Can you adapt it to a function over two dimensions? (Consider the distance from the origin!)

For the second, what do you know about integrable functions? Must they not be bounded? Find a way to violate this, or any other condition you think an integrable function must satisfy.